# Programmatically update tileset

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

Mapbox data management workflow [documentation](https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/) (or my unserstanding of it) seems to be lacking.

I currently have a custom `style` with some custom `tilesets` added to it. Whenever the data of my `tileset` needs to be updated, is there and elegant way to update the existing data through the API and retain any styling for a particular `style`?

My best guess for what that workflow would look like:

1. Request Mapbox S3 credentials
2. Upload data to new `tileset`
3. Retrieve new `tileset` ID
4. List `style`'s current `tileset` IDs
5. Remove old `tileset` from `style`
6. Add new `tileset` to `style`
7. Restyle new `tileset` to match old `tileset`

I'm hoping I'm missing something obvious that lets me do the following instead:

1. Update `style`'s `tileset`'s data

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can upload data to replace an existing tileset, no need to do all that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Mapbox's `mapbox-upload` Node module to replace an existing tileset: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-upload

```
var progress = upload({
    file: __dirname + '/test.mbtiles', // Path to mbtiles file on disk.
    account: 'test', // Mapbox user account.
    accesstoken: 'validtoken', // A valid Mapbox API secret token with the uploads:write scope enabled.
    mapid: 'test.upload', // The identifier of the map to create or update.
    name: 'My upload' // Optional name to set, otherwise a default such as original.geojson will be used.
});
```

Set the `mapid` property to the id of your existing tileset. Real-life example [here](https://github.com/OpenCouncilData/Aggregator/blob/master/upload-mapbox.js).

Similarly via the command line:

```
$ npm install --global mapbox-upload
$ export MapboxAccessToken=<access token with uploads:write scope enabled>
$ mapbox-upload username.dataid /path/to/file
```

Comment: Yeah, but using curl is fiddly because it's a two-step process, and you have to retrieve the ID from the first step to pass to the second step. You might as well use the all-in-one tool unless there's a compelling reason (eg, a server that doesn't let you install anything) not to.