# Partial update of mapbox tileset

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have a mapbox tileset with lots of small data points and I regularly need to update one data point at a time. Is it possible to programmatically update a mapbox tileset in a partial way? [These instructions](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/upload-curl/) from the mapbox docs and [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47480711/programmatically-update-tileset) explain how to *overwrite* a tileset file. This is useful but seems like overkill if I just want to update 1 point out of thousands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're after is Mapbox's [tippecanoe](https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe#selectively-remove-and-replace-features-census-tracts-to-update-a-tileset).

Comment: There are several examples on https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-tiling-service/examples/ , but I don't see anything that shows how to update a single point of data in a tileset. Do you know of an example of this?

Answer (score 0):

No. But probably the better way to update a source is using the tiling service API: https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/mapbox-tiling-service/#replace-a-tileset-source

Comment: And I specifically said that's not possible.